# Simpler way of showing $\int_0^{1/2}\csc(\pi t)-\frac{1}{\pi t}<+\infty$.

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-series, estimation, upper-lower-bounds, pointwise-convergence

I am going over the proof of the Dirichlet-Jordan criterion for pointwise convergence of Fourier series (in *J. Duoandikoetxea*'s book *Fourier Analysis*). At a certain point he claims that
$$
\int_0^{1/2}\big(\csc(\pi t)-\frac{1}{\pi t}\big)\,dt<+\infty
$$
without further explanation.

One can verify this directly since the integrand has an elementary primitive, but it involves calculating the primitive of $\csc x$, which is tricky (at least the proof I once knew). Also, one could observe that $1/(\pi z)$ is the principal part of the Laurent series of $\csc z$ around $0$ and thus that the integrand is a holomorphic function in the unit disk, but that seems like an overkill.

Is there any elementary way of showing the above estimate? Am I missing some obvious argument here?

Comment: Yes $f(t) = \frac{t}{\sin(t)}$ is $C^1$ on $|t| < \pi$ and $f(0) = 1$  thus $\frac{f(t)-1}{t} = \frac{1}{\sin(t)}-\frac{1}{t}$ is bounded on $|t|< \pi/2$

Comment: @reuns Oh, absolutely! I don't know how I missed that. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reuns showed one way in a comment, here is another: as $t\to 0$, 
$$\sin(\pi t) = \pi t+O(t^3)$$ 
hence
$$\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t} = 1+O(t^2)$$
and taking the reciprocal yields 
$$\frac{\pi t}{\sin(\pi t)} = 1+O(t^2)$$
Divide by $\pi t$ to get 
$$\frac{1}{\sin(\pi t)} = \frac{1}{\pi t}+O(t)$$
so the integrand tends to zero as $t\to 0$, in particular it is bounded.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was a bit skeptical about the "taking the reciprocal" part... Neat answer, thank you!! =)